# Online photo contest organizer

Tags: file-management, photography

I have to organize the images for a small academic photo contest. Which tool would be the best?

- Between 100-200 images
- About 10 should be quickly compared and selected by a small jury (3/4 people)
- The first selection could be done "online" and remotely by each
- The 10 finalist will be presented to a larger jury which will vote for the best 3
- OS can be Linux (preferred) or Windows.

Comment: That is 1 *to* 200 images yes? (rather than 1200 or 1/200th of an image)

Comment: sorry 100 to 200 images; not many I know but the process potentially involves many comparison.

Comment: Yes that was what I thought but I just wanted to confirm. Don't know anything *specifically* for contests unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but I have an online solution that could help others. I am one of the developers of https://pollunit.com and with our tool you can create polls about pictures.

This is an example for an logo poll:

[image]

We also have a free version. The features are:

- Up to 40 participants per poll
- Up to 20 photos per poll
- No registration necessary (also not for voting)
- Different voting types (Range Voting, Dot Voting, Boolean...)

Our paid account can do more:

- Up to 100000 participants per poll
- Up to 4000 photos per poll
- Various security measures

**Update:**

We released a new PollUnit type "photo contest". More infos can be found here: https://pollunit.com/en/photo-contest

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any software that does that, but you can always use free platforms like Facebook (with a private group for the jury) or Flickr.

The small jury can like or comment the images to select them, and it allows them to do it online. Then you can "open" the private group to more users. The only drawback is that you'll have to check the winners manually.

I've found [this article](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/26502-how-to-organize-a-contest-on-facebook) on organizing contests on Facebook. Again, it's using Facebook but it might be a bit more "organized".